# How to download canvas from HTML5 as a png file BUT with the transparency included?

Tags: javascript, processing

So I am currently using Processing to render to a canvas, and I am setting some pixels to transparent like this:

```
stroke(firstV, secondV, thirdV, alphaV);
point(x, y);
```

If the pixel is transparent then `alphaV=0`.

The code to download the image i borrowed from online:

```
 function downloadCanvas(link, canvasId, filename) {
    link.href = document.getElementById(canvasId).toDataURL('image/png');
    link.download = filename;
}

document.getElementById('download').addEventListener('click', function() {
    downloadCanvas(this, 'mycanvas', 'test.png');
}, false);
```

but look at the image (compare to a TRUE png transparent file):

[image]

right is transparent but mine left is not.

How can i preserve transparency in a png from a HTML5 canvas ?

Any help you be great!
Thanks!

Comment: Can you please post a [mcve]? Note that this should not be your full program, but just enough code for us to run ourselves to see the problem.

Comment: The image on the left looks like it does have transparency. What exactly is the issue? Also, are you using processing or p5.js? The alpha argument to stroke() can actually be a number from 255 (non-transparent) to 0 (fully transparent) and other numbers in-between representing partial-transparency.